# Highlight active Admin Menu when added though add_menu_page

Tags: admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page

I added a direct link to a page in the admin menu with the add_menu_page function.
Once I click on the link, the About page edit screen opens, great.
The problem though, i want the About menu item i added to be higlighted in blue.

`add_menu_page( 'About1', 'About', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=87&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-editor-help', 7 );`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'parent_file', 'parent_file_hover' );

function parent_file_hover( $parent_file )   {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'post.php')
        $parent_file = "post.php?post={$_REQUEST['post']}&action=edit";
    elseif($pagenow == 'post-new.php')
        $parent_file = "post-new.php?post_type={$_REQUEST['post_type']}";
    return $parent_file;
}
```